# Get last insert ID in peewee ORM (python)

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I would like to retrieve the last insert ID (for use in a second table as a relation), however, I do not know how to get it. I am using the peewee ORM.

The table 'readings' in the database 'nest' has a column 'id' (int (11) auto_increment, primary key).

```
import time
from peewee import *

database = MySQLDatabase('nest', **{'user': 'nest'})

class Readings(BaseModel):
time = DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'readings'

dt = Readings.insert(time=time.strftime("%x %X"))
dt.execute();
print "Last insert id:", dt.last_insert_id(database, Readings);
```

The last line is where I am stuck. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for the the help, the answer was really easy. Here is the correct code:

```
import time
from peewee import *

database = MySQLDatabase('nest', **{'user': 'nest'})

class Readings(BaseModel):
    time = DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'readings'

dt = Readings.insert(time=time.strftime("%x %X"))
print "Last insert id: %i" % dt.execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can direct fetch id of that insert record like below

import time
from peewee import *

database = MySQLDatabase('nest', **{'user': 'nest'})

class Readings(BaseModel):
time = DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'readings'

dt = Readings(time=time.strftime("%x %X"))
dt.save()

print "Last insert id:"+str(dt.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

just in case , you can get the id right after insert

```
huey = User()
huey.username = 'Huey'
huey.save()
huey.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't require semi colons!

Just a note... InsertQuery.execute() should actually return the last insert id. If you want to call last_insert_id() you need to pass in the cursor that was used to execute the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot - the semicolons come automatically - I just posted the correct code based on your answer.